# programs paralyzing each other on the server (c++ with openMP and python)

Tags: c++, python, openmp

I have an urgent problem because my time is running out: I let my calculations process on a server with 8 cores therefore I'm using openMP in my c++ code and it works fine. Of course I'm not the only one who is using the server, so my capacity is not always 800%CPU.

But it happened now several times that someone who started his python prog on the machine paralyzed mine and his prog completely: Although I was still using around 500%CPU the code was running approx. 100x slower - for me and the other guy. *Do you have an idea what the reason could be, how to prevent it?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Emil Vikström listed, there are several reasons which can cause such a paralysis. I could fix the problem by enabling dynamic adjustment of the number of threads available:

```
omp_set_dynamic(1);
```

I assumed that it's on by default. It is not.

Answer (score 5):

There can be a number of reasons for this, for example:

- Increased failure rate in the branch prediction
- Exhausted CPU cache
- Filled up the memory bus
- Too much context switching (this have an effect on many things, including all the previous points)

Comment: the strange thing is: the python prog seems to use only one kernel, 100%CPU is showing up on top, but it thwarts me completely.

Comment: Is there a lot of data shuffling involved? Maybe the CPU cache is filled so data is being expunged from the cache? The CPU performs terrible if that's the case since the cache is much faster than RAM.

Comment: I'm dealing with quite large matrices but they are all shared between the processors, only small values are exchanged. (Can it be a problem that a function which is often called has the "#pragma omp parallel"-block in its function body?)